# Invertibility of elements in a Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $X=L^1\cap L^2$, and $\hat{X}$ be the Banach algebra of the image under Fourier transform of $X$. Then do the unital extension $1\dot{+}\hat{X}$ of $X$ by adding a constant function with the norm given by:
$$
|c+\hat{f}|_{1\dot{+}\hat{X}}=|c|+|\hat{f}|_{\hat{X}}
$$

Now my question is: for an element $f=\alpha+\hat{h}$ in $1\dot{+}\hat{X}$, what is the necessary and sufficient condition for $f$ to be invertible? I was informed that this may have something to do with the Wiener theorem, which is probably the one dealing with the invertibility of an element of the Wiener algebra consisting of functions with absolutely convergent Fourier coefficients, but I didn't see how it works. So can someone help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "Banach algebra of ..."? Is it the closure of $\mathcal F(L^1\cap L^2)\subseteq C_0(\mathbb R)\cap L^2$? In which norm? The multiplication is pointwise product?

Comment: In unital commutative Banach algebra an element $a$ is invertible iff $\chi(a)\neq 0$ for every character $\chi.$

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk Yes, it's under pointwise production, and norm in $\hat{X}$ is given by that of its preimage in $X$ which is given by $||_{L^1}+||_{L^2}$.

Comment: In fact you consider the Banach space $L^1\cap L^2$ on $\mathbb R$ with convolution. Is it true that the norm is a Banach algebra norm? I.e. $||f*g||_1+||f*g||_2\leq(||f||_1+||f||_2)(||g||_1+||g||_2)$ ?

Comment: It should be so. One can use Young's inequality to show this since $f$ and $g$ both lie in $L^1\cap L^2$.

Comment: It seems to work with the young's inequality indeed: $||f∗g||_1+||f∗g||_2\leq||f||_1||g||_1+||f||_1||g||_2\leq(||f||_1+||f||_2)(||g||_1+||g||_2)$

Comment: Consider $A=L^1(\mathbb R)$ with convolution and let $\tilde A$ be the unitization. Then every character on $\tilde A$ is either $f\dot{+}\lambda\mapsto\lambda$ or $f\dot{+}\lambda\mapsto \hat f(y),\ y\in\mathbb R,$ where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier thransform of $f.$ Thus $f\dot{+}\lambda\in\tilde A$ is invertible iff $\hat{f}+\lambda\in C_0(\mathbb R)\dot{+}\mathbb C$ is nowhere zero. You should be able to do the same in $L^1\cap L^2.$ If you can show that every character on $L^1\cap L^2$ is a restriction of a character on $L^1$ then you have the same criterion.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk: Thanks for telling me these. I actually also realized the relationship between the Banach algebra $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with convolution and the Banach algebra of Fourier transform, but this is about the invertibility of the element in $1+L^1$, not $1+\hat{L^1}$. So the question is how can one characterize the character of $1+\hat{L^1}$.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk: To be more explicitly, what you told me is about the invertibility of elements in $1+L^1$ under convolution, whose character is nothing but constant plus Fourier transform of $L^1$. In this case the invertibility is totally decided on whether this character vanishes or not. But what I am asking is the invertibility of another Banach algebra $1+\hat{L^1}$, and I don't know anything about its character. How should one characterize it?

Comment: If you consider $\hat{L^1}$ with the norm of the preimage (as you do it for $L^1\cap L^2$), then $\mathbb C+\hat{L^1}$ is the same as $\mathbb C+{L^1}.$ (The Fourier transform is injective.)